# VBA Powerpoint Shape.Linkformat.Update opens linked Workbook even though an instance is already open

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a Powerpoint presentation that has shapes which are linked to several Excel
Worbooks. The links are to cell ranges within the workbooks. I wrote a macro to programmatically
update those links but I'm facing an issue with it. Since I have a lot of links I don't want Powerpoint to open the workbook for each link to it and close it again (which happens normally), which is why I open them beforehand so Powerpoint can reuse the Workbook to update the link. But it seems as though it can't find it.

Here's the macro to update the links.

```
Sub RefreshSlide() 'SelectedWorkbooks As Variant)
    
    Dim osld As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim oshp As PowerPoint.shape
    Dim SelectedWorkbooks() As Variant
    Dim LinkedWorkbookPath As Variant
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

    xlApp.Visible = True

    SelectedWorkbooks = Array(Workbook1Path) ' Simplified, in reality more Workbooks. And 
        
    For Each LinkedWorkbookPath In SelectedWorkbooks

         xlApp.Workbooks.Open (CStr(Dir(LinkedWorkbookPath)))

    Next LinkedWorkbookPath
    
    For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
            If oshp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
                Withslidelinkedworkbooksource = Left(oshp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, InStr(oshp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, "!") - 1)
                If IsInArray(CStr(Withslidelinkedworkbooksource), SelectedWorkbooks) Then
                    
                    oshp.LinkFormat.Update

                End If
            End If

        Next oshp
    Next osld
    
End Sub
```

When I execute the code above, it stops at `oshp.LinkFormat.Update` and Excel throws an error saying it can't open two Workbooks with the same name. That implies that `oshp.LinkFormat.Update` can't find the workbook.

I also found out that if I open the Workbook like this:

```
        Shell "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE " & Chr(34) & CStr(Workbook1Path) & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus
        Sleep 5000
```

it works.

I'd really appreciate an explanation on how `.LinkFormat.Update` works.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

have you tried this [Presentation.UpdateLinks method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.updatelinks) ever?

> [To update all the links in a presentation at once, use the UpdateLinks method.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/PowerPoint.LinkFormat.Update?source=docs#:%7E:text=To%20update%20all%20the%20links%20in%20a%20presentation%20at%20once%2C%20use%20the%20UpdateLinks%20method.)

or [LinkFormat.AutoUpdate property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.linkformat.autoupdate)?

> [sh.LinkFormat.AutoUpdate = ppUpdateOptionManual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.linkformat#:%7E:text=sh.LinkFormat.AutoUpdate%20%3D%20ppUpdateOptionManual)

## Solution 2

I can think of at least two directions to try to see:

- 1. When you want to update an oshp from the same Workbook (try to check if it is the same Workbook first) and then start another Exce with **New** or **CreateObject**,

```
set xlAppN = new Excel.Application
```

or

```
set xlAppN =createobject("excel.application")
```

as long as there is enough memory, you can open multiple Excel instances and then open Workbooks with the same name in them.
I just don't understand why you have to

```
xlApp.Visible = True
```

is this necessary? *Why not do it in the background?*

This direction's principle and the reason why it works is that you can use **Shell** and it's worked.

- 2. The previous one is not ideal because it may run out of memory (because you don't seem to want to use them up and close them right away) and take up too many system resources. So we should use a **Dictionary** to store your opened **Workbooks**, where the **Key** of each element is the **full file name of the workbook** (as long as they are all in the same operating system, to ensure that there will be no duplication as long as the name will not be duplicated, if it will, use the **Collection** to store it instead. (Details below **3**.) And the **Value** is the **Workbook object**.
- 3. If you use a **Collection** to store it, the elements can be a **one-dimensional array with two elements**. The first element holds the **full name**, and the second holds the opened **Workbook object**.

The final key question is whether you can determine in the program which Workbook is the source of the link in **oshp**, so that you can find the corresponding Workbook when you want to call the **LinkFormat.Update** method on it. (I think this should not be difficult, after all, it is a **link type** and must store the path of the Workbook for Update.)

### the Code

should be like this: *(my code run **error-free**)*

```vb
Sub RefreshSlide() 'SelectedWorkbooks As Variant)
    
    Rem use a Dictionary to store your opened Workbooks
    'Dim wbDictionary As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim wbDictionary As Object
    Set wbDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim osld As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim oshp As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim SelectedWorkbooks() As Variant
    Dim LinkedWorkbookPath As Variant
    
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

    Rem is this necessary for you? Why not do it in the background?
    xlApp.Visible = True ':xlapp.UserControl=True 'default is false and Quit will be call at the end

    'SelectedWorkbooks = Array(Workbook1Path) ' Simplified, in reality more Workbooks. And
    

'    For Each LinkedWorkbookPath In SelectedWorkbooks
'
'         xlApp.Workbooks.Open (CStr(Dir(LinkedWorkbookPath)))
'
'    Next LinkedWorkbookPath
    
    
    For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
            If oshp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
            
'                Withslidelinkedworkbooksource = Left(oshp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, InStr(oshp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, "!") - 1)
'                If IsInArray(CStr(Withslidelinkedworkbooksource), SelectedWorkbooks) Then

                    Rem  store your opened Workbooks, where the Key of each element is the full file name of the workbook (as long as they are all in the same operating system, to ensure that there will be no duplication as long as the name will not be duplicated, if it will, use the Collection to store it instead.
                    Rem  And the Value is the Workbook object.
                    LinkedWorkbookPath = oshp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
                    If Not wbDictionary.Exists(LinkedWorkbookPath) Then
                        Set wbDictionary(LinkedWorkbookPath) = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(LinkedWorkbookPath)
                    End If
                
                                        
                    Rem   In my test I found that actually let Update run in the background,
                    Rem   it only opens one file at a time and closes after Update, it will not cause file name conflict, is this bad?
                    Rem   Why do you have to open all of them first and keep them open? Unless your source files are so large that it takes a lot of time to open them each time. Is that the case?
                    oshp.LinkFormat.Update

'                End If

            End If

        Next oshp
    Next osld
    
    
    'xlapp.Quit    'if need,do this
    
End Sub
```

*Because I do not have the relevant files, I can only write and set by imagination, and can not actually test. Please forgive me. Or can you give me a set of **samples** for me to test?*

## Solution 3

I thought of is first put all the **SourceFullName** values in the **Key** of the **Dictionary**, and then **group** the **oshp** by holding them in a Collection as the Value of the Dictionary, then updating the same path (i.e., the same workbook) oshps first, instead of traversing them in the slides to apply Update method first. This may be by far the least costly way to do it. I don't have so many Linked Shapes to test this, maybe you'll try to see if is it fast or slow still.

```vb
Sub RefreshSlide() 'SelectedWorkbooks As Variant)
    
    Rem use a Dictionary to store your oshps object and their .LinkFormat.SourceFullName value
    Rem    , where Key is SourceFullName value and value is a Collection of the oshp objects
    'Dim wbDictionary As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim wbDictionary As Object, key, oshpsCollection As New VBA.Collection
    Set wbDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim osld As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim oshp As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim SelectedWorkbooks() As Variant
    Dim LinkedWorkbookPath As Variant
    
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

    Rem is this necessary for you? Why not do it in the background?
    xlApp.Visible = True ':xlapp.UserControl=True 'default is false and Quit will be call at the end

    'SelectedWorkbooks = Array(Workbook1Path) ' Simplified, in reality more Workbooks. And
    

'    For Each LinkedWorkbookPath In SelectedWorkbooks
'
'         xlApp.Workbooks.Open (CStr(Dir(LinkedWorkbookPath)))
'
'    Next LinkedWorkbookPath
    
    
    For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
            'If oshp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
            Select Case oshp.Type
                Case msoLinkedOLEObject, msoChart
            
'                Withslidelinkedworkbooksource = Left(oshp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, InStr(oshp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, "!") - 1)
'                If IsInArray(CStr(Withslidelinkedworkbooksource), SelectedWorkbooks) Then

                    Rem  store your oshp messages , where the Key of each element is the full file name of the source workbook
                    Rem  And the Value is a Collection of oshp objects link to the same workbook.
                    LinkedWorkbookPath = oshp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
                    If Not wbDictionary.Exists(LinkedWorkbookPath) Then
                        Set oshpsCollection = Nothing
                        oshpsCollection.Add oshp
                        Set wbDictionary(LinkedWorkbookPath) = oshpsCollection
                    Else
                        wbDictionary(LinkedWorkbookPath).Add oshp
                        Set wbDictionary(LinkedWorkbookPath) = wbDictionary(LinkedWorkbookPath)
                    End If
                
                    
                    Rem   do this in the next For Each ... Next loop
                    'oshp.LinkFormat.Update

'                End If

            End Select

        Next oshp
    Next osld
    
    
    Rem Update oshps LinkFormat one by one by a group of the same source workbook
    Rem Does one oshp correspond to one workbook?
    Rem      or multiple oshps correspond to one workbook? If there are many, then this method is applicable(For example, I used the Type of msoChart before, not only msoLinkedOLEObject is a bookwork)
    Rem      , otherwise, it is meaningless.
    For Each key In wbDictionary
        For Each oshp In wbDictionary(key)
            oshp.LinkFormat.Update ' this method must be opening the workbook to achieve
        Next
    Next key
    
    Rem if you don't want Excel to stay then it will quit at the end itself, this line can be omitted
    'xlapp.Quit    'if need,do this
    
    Rem if you want to keep Excel you opened stay then use these two lines.
    xlApp.UserControl = True
    xlApp.Visible = True
    
    
End Sub
```

### Speed Test

564 slides and about 564 linked shapes:

[image]
[image]

PowerPoint 2013

Tested Excel files (only two):

> 1.xlsm  24KB

> 2.xlsb 20KB

[image]

Comment: Yes the problem is that  Presentation.UpdateLinks updates all links which isn't what I always want. I have now tested it with sh.LinkFormat.AutoUpdate = ppUpdateOptionManual but that doesn't work either

Comment: @dawit This is my current solution. My answer has been updated, please refer to it.

Comment: @ Oscar Sun That's very interesting. I also used to have a version of the code with a dictionary but I scrapped it because I had to pass it around from powerpoint to excel to powerpoint again which resulted in Automation Errors probably because of wrong initialization. Thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately I can't give you sample data because it's my job and my boss would kill me. Keeping the Workbooks visible is for another step in the update phase where different macros could throw errows which I'd like to know about.

Comment: To give you at least some background. I work with a Powerpoint presentation with at least 400 slides which have 100-150 links to various Excel workbooks. This makes updating all slide links very slow if it's done the normal way by opening and closing a workbook on demand. Which is what powerpoint usually does. I'm also curious about the UserControl property. Does that allow me to keep the Excel Application  running past the completion of my procedure?

Comment: @dawit Yes. [UserControl property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.usercontrol) it is. And I realized after testing that there must be a command to start the workbook in the definition of the Update method, so as long as this method is called, there is no way to avoid the switch problem. And in logic, it must be so, not open, and how to read it? I would like to use Dictionary, but you have to pay attention to how to operate it, I do not know how your Dictionary is implemented,

Comment: @dawit  What I thought of is to first put all the **SourceFullName** values in the **Value** of the **Dictionary**, and then **sort** the value to update the same path (i.e., the same workbook) **oshp**s first, instead of traversing them in the slides first, so that **each workbook will only be opened and closed one time**, you will not even have to deal with hundreds of workbooks, right? Even so, this is by far the least costly way to do it. I will add another code to show you, at the end of my original answer.